# IE, Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, opera

When I'm creating a web page, every time I start it with creating a layout in photoshop, than I slice the images, than in Dreamweaver I start to code it HTML, CSS and Javascript (Jquery) and I'm using PHP if I want to use a database.

When coding the page with HTML and CSS, every time when finishing a block of codes (div, span etc) I'm checking in with Firefox, Google Chrome, Opera, IE and Safari. In Firefox, Chrome and Opera everything it's okay, but in IE and Safari some divs are non-visibile, images floats around, invisible images etc.

This is how I create a web page. How are you creating your own web page? Where you start? What am I supposed to do when things like this happens (invisible elements on IE or Safari)? I always googled it and found that on older versions of Internet Explorer or on the same version I need to implement a plus of codes. I have no experience in older versions and sometimes I don't know why this happens. I don't know where to search, or what keyword am I need to search.

For example I need to use border-radius, but in IE it seems to be broken. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this a good question for this site? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: For me, it's not, it's very broad and has no concrete answer.

Comment: @Rafal why don't you flag it?

Answer (score 1):

When I start a web page I layout my main parts of the site for instance the header, menu and footer divs and work my way in.

Unfortunately for web devs there are differences in the ways certain browsers display elements.  To debug these problems use a developer toolkit like firebug for FF, these help a lot as you can pick apart the page.  Chrome has a very good built in kit, IEs is a bit poor it comes up when you press F12.

border-radius is not supported in IE, I like to use this tool to generate my border radius CSS as it works accross all other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

border-radius is available in IE9 and should work without problems.

About how I work:

1. I receive the layout (from the designer and the sliced images) and I'm coding it - usually I use SublimeText 2.
2. Test it in Firefox and Chrome (moz and webkit). Web dev tools really helps.
3. Test in Opera - it usually works just fine
4. Write other CSS files for IE (you know, for compatibility reasons)

I would recommend taking a good wordpres theme and look in the CSS files. It might help you.